# How can I use OAuth to replace OpenID for federated login

Tags: oauth, openid

I am currently using OpenID as a relying-party to implement federated login on a website I'm developing.  However cursory Google searches indicate that OpenID does not play well with web-services which I'd like to expose.  However every tutorial, explanation or library seems oriented towards gaining access to a resource held by a 3rd party, Flickr library, Gmail address-book etc. Is it possible to use OAuth for this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: "I'd like to expose" Doesnt that mean you let third-party sites perform actions on behalf of your users? Please explain the role of the third-parties with respect to the users.

Comment: Letting a 3rd party do actions on behalf of my users really isn't a use-case here.  The webservice would mainly exist as a support mechanism for non-browser implementations.

Comment: Sorry, I still dont get your problem. Please search around for "openid vs oauth" and then "openid and oauth" in Google and SO; there are tons of resources on this question.

Comment: I've actually spent quite a bit of time on both google & SO looking at this.  Basically it looks like OAuth just doesn't handle the authentication case except through some provider specific extensions such as twitter.

Comment: That's correct, OAuth doesn't handle identity/authentication natively. However, the next generation OpenID protocol, OpenID Connect, is built on top of OAuth2, which will give us a standard identity/authentication layer built on top of OAuth's authorization layer.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is not an appropriate technology to use here.